# How to highlight 4 borders of a table cell with border-collapse collapse

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to highlight the borders of cells having the class `active`.

The problem is the table's `border-collapse` property is set to  `collapse`, which will hide the `top` and `left` border of cells(except for left most and top row cells). This is causing an issue whereby the highlight class(`active`) is not highlighting the `top` and `left` borders.

You can find the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2ahfP/).

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding: 10px">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>2.2</td>
            <td class="active">2.3</td>
            <td>2.4</td>
            <td>2.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>3.2</td>
            <td>3.3</td>
            <td>3.4</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4.1</td>
            <td>4.2</td>
            <td>4.3</td>
            <td>4.4</td>
            <td>4.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5.1</td>
            <td>5.2</td>
            <td>5.3</td>
            <td>5.4</td>
            <td>5.5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td.active {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

td.brdr-b-hide {
    border-bottom: none;
}
td.brdr-r-hide {
    border-right: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e){
        var target = $(e.currentTarget);

        if(e.ctrlKey && target.hasClass('active')){
            target.removeClass('active');
        } else if(e.ctrlKey) {
            target.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('table td.active').removeClass('active');
            target.addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

One of the solutions I'm working on is to hide the `border-right` of the cell in the left of the `active` cell and the `border-bottom` of the cell at the top.

I'm not so happy with the solution since the `active` class is applied and removed when a cell is clicked. Here my solution need to find the `prev` cell and the top cell and apply/remove the corresponding classes to/from them.

You can find the proposed solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2ahfP/27/).

My question is, is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: you can try the css property [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/outline)

Comment: The collapse isn't the issue it seems, remove it and the same thing continues to happen. It's like the cells borders are overlapping reading from top left to bottom right as far as priority goes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Define **border-style:double**. Write like this:

```
td.active {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-style:double;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/2ahfP/18/

Comment: That's also not entirely correct. border-width: 3px won't work.

Comment: @Sandeep Thanks, I think this will do it for now. What abt cross browser compatibility ie(IE!!!)

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
td.active {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

The difference between outline and border is that outline won't add to the elements total width or height. Also the border-collapse property won't affect the outline.

Comment: That sort of works, problem I see is with two active cells beside each other you get double borders.

Comment: @AntonNiklasson It will cause a double border where to adjacent cells have the active class.